# How to handle ties with n-grams and the max function in Python?

Tags: python, max, n-gram

In my program I'm finding n-grams and printing out how many there are within a dataset.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram For those who don't know what an n-gram is.

Here's my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import sys
from string import punctuation
def tokenize(text, ngrams=1):
    tokens = text.split()
    return [tuple(tokens[i:i+ngrams]) for i in range(len(tokens)-ngrams+1)]

line = ""
for i in sys.stdin:
    stripped = i.strip(punctuation)
    line += stripped.lower()
for n in range(1, 10):
    a = tokenize(line, n)
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in a:
        d[i] += 1
    result = max(d.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])
    if(result[1] >= 3):
        s = ' '.join(result[0])
        print('{:<6} {:<0} {:<0} {:<10}'.format(str(result[1]), str(n) + "-grams ", "|", s))
```

Here's an example output of my program with a dataset:

```
10     1-grams  | and
3      2-grams  | balloonman whistles
3      3-grams  | balloonman whistles far
3      4-grams  | balloonman whistles far and
3      5-grams  | balloonman whistles far and wee
```

And here is what I should be getting (ignore formatting differences):

```
10 1-grams       | and
3 2-grams        | balloonman whistles
3 2-grams        | whistles far
3 2-grams        | far and
3 2-grams        | and wee
3 3-grams        | balloonman whistles far
3 3-grams        | whistles far and
3 3-grams        | far and wee
3 4-grams        | balloonman whistles far and
3 4-grams        | whistles far and wee
3 5-grams        | balloonman whistles far and wee
```

It seems the problem is when I am finding the max of my items in my defaultdict, I am only getting one of the 3 3-grams for example, but I want to get all 3 3-grams. Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup that is the reason. From https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

> If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered. This is consistent with other sort-stability preserving tools such as sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc, reverse=True)[0] and heapq.nlargest(1, iterable, key=keyfunc).

Just find the maximum as you're doing and then use the max value i.e. result[1], and get the complete list of most common n grams, with a list comprehension.